# R.java was modified manually! Reverting to generated version

Tags: android

I added one xml file in layout. After that this error is coming. But the problem is I haven't touched R.java file. 
Now in my new activity i m going to set its content view as my newly created xml file, but when i m doing R.layout., the newly created xml is not coming in suggestion. Do anybody have any idea how to correct this.
I have cleaned my project several times but it is not working.

Answer (score 5):

**Delete** `R.java` and let eclipse regenerate it, then **project --> clean** will fix it.

Comment: did u checked whether your xml is in res --> layout ??

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have any existing errors in your code, if yes correct it and then try refreshing and building your Project.If your Project is properly build,you will get the new xml file in suggestion

Comment: thanks for your quick reply, I tried that but still it is not coming. And also I don't have any error in my project.

Comment: Did you build your Project? Right click on Project->Build Project

Answer (score 2):

It happened to one of my Eclipse projects today. This is what fixed it mysteriously. Don't know why or how.

Changed **Properties->Android->Project Build Target** to a higher (different) version of Android and hit the **Apply** button. Then did a clean build. The problem went away.

After the above steps, I could even go back to the original **Project Build Target** without the problem re-appearing.

Comment: Worked with me. :)

Answer (score 1):

May this Help you...

I think your xml file name might be having `some capital letters or some special characters`..

Delete them and then try again to run the project..

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning the project this will do the work.

Comment: Thanks i tried that but still it is not working any other suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

make sure your not importing any thing that ends with com.R 
make sure your naming convention of the layout is correct

Answer (score 0):

R.java file have all the resources IDs provided to resources(drawables, layouts, styles etc) either by Programmer, or generated through sdk. So check your xml files as well as your drawable folders. If any of them including wrong format it will show an error in R.java file like sometime R.java is not generating or our class file shows R.id.xxx is not found or R.class is not defined error.Then clean your project.

Comment: No I don't have any error in R.java file or any other file.
Instead of that I was socked, because my newly created xml file's entry is also there in my R.java file. But still it is not coming in suggestion box of R.layout.now_my_file_name

Answer (score 0):

There must be some mistake in one of your xml files. Eclipse does not always show error messages if there is something wrong with your xml. Mostly code gets errors, in this case 'R', so you will need to go through your xml manually, it could just be a simple mistake. Good luck

Comment: even in my xml I have not added anything except my form. Means to check for the errors I have not added any buttons or any other control on that. But still it is creating problem

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. Cleaning project didn't solve the issue and there was no error in the code or the uppercase or spaces in file names.

The solution was going to a popup window which came when you choose PROJECT-->CLEAN and then UNcheck the "Start a build immediately" option. Clean the project. Close and reopen Eclipse and then build the project (PROJECT-->BUILD).

The question remains why simple clean and build without closing Eclipse didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on Project->Bulid Path->Configure Build Path
ther you see error android-support-v4.jar remove this library and add library again this works fine for me.

Else 
Try
Go to gen Folder delete R.java and from Project option choose Clean Project.

Answer (score 0):

Very late on the scene...

I had this line mysteriously appear at the start of my imports:

```
import android.R;
```

I deleted it and shazam error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar error, but when I import new project to my eclipse. and the solution was, I should check the option (copy project to work space) specially when our project has library.