# Failed To Launch Test

Tags: android, junit

I am facing a strange issue while Running Android Unit Test Cases:

```
[2015-01-29 17:47:24 - RFStackTest] R.java was modified manually! Reverting to generated version!
[2015-01-29 17:47:36 - Unable to launch cygpath. Is Cygwin on the path?] java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cygpath": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
[2015-01-29 17:47:47 - RFStackTest] ------------------------------
[2015-01-29 17:47:47 - RFStackTest] Android Launch!
[2015-01-29 17:47:47 - RFStackTest] adb is running normally.
[2015-01-29 17:47:47 - RFStackTest] Performing android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner JUnit launch
[2015-01-29 17:47:47 - RFStackTest] Automatic Target Mode: using device '192.168.33.125:5000'
[2015-01-29 17:47:47 - RFStackTest] Uploading RFStackTest.apk onto device '192.168.33.125:5000'
[2015-01-29 17:47:51 - RFStackTest] Installing RFStackTest.apk...
[2015-01-29 17:47:52 - RFStackTest] Success!
[2015-01-29 17:47:52 - RFStackTest] Launching instrumentation android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner on 192.168.33.125:5000
[2015-01-29 17:47:52 - RFStackTest] Failed to launch test
[2015-01-29 17:48:09 - RFStackTest] Dx 
trouble writing output: already prepared
[2015-01-29 17:48:09 - RFStackTest] ------------------------------
[2015-01-29 17:48:09 - RFStackTest] Android Launch!
[2015-01-29 17:48:09 - RFStackTest] adb is running normally.
[2015-01-29 17:48:09 - RFStackTest] Performing android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner JUnit launch
[2015-01-29 17:48:10 - RFStackTest] Automatic Target Mode: using device '192.168.33.125:5000'
[2015-01-29 17:48:10 - RFStackTest] Uploading RFStackTest.apk onto device '192.168.33.125:5000'
[2015-01-29 17:48:14 - RFStackTest] Installing RFStackTest.apk...
[2015-01-29 17:48:16 - RFStackTest] Success!
[2015-01-29 17:48:16 - RFStackTest] Launching instrumentation android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner on 192.168.33.125:5000
[2015-01-29 17:48:16 - RFStackTest] Failed to launch test
```

How Can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try to Delete R.java and let eclipse regenerate it, by rebuilding the project then project --> clean will fix it.

Provided by [R.java was modified manually! Reverting to generated version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17463460/r-java-was-modified-manually-reverting-to-generated-version)